# Missing background style on Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D few examples

Tags: documentation, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Missing background style on following Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D examples.
Would you update it, please?

- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/guiviewer3d/#registercontextmenucallback-id-callback
- https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/guiviewer3d/#setcanvasclickbehavior-config

Images:

- [Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D registerContextMenuCallback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c5Fn.png)
- [Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D setCanvasClickBehavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNHPH.png)

Comment: Thanks always for pointing this out - the Documentation team has been notified to correct these, thanks again!

Comment: It's my pleasure.